# Configure http basic auth on EJB web service in Wildfly

Tags: web-services, authentication, glassfish, ejb, wildfly

I work with Glassfish and in glassfish-ejb-jar.xml I'm able to secure ejb exposed web service like this (http basic auth)

```
<ejb>
  <ejb-name>Command</ejb-name>
  <webservice-endpoint>
    <port-component-name>Command</port-component-name>
    <endpoint-address-uri>NPI/command</endpoint-address-uri>
    <login-config>
      <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
      <realm>NPI</realm>
    </login-config>
  </webservice-endpoint>
</ejb>
```

I'm looking for a similar way to do it when deploying to Wildfly but so far I wasn't able to find a solution.

All I have found is a description how to do it in web.xml but I guess that asks for web services to be exposed via servlet cointainer.

Are there any Wildfly specific deployment descriptors or methods to get the same results as with glassfish ejb descriptor on glassfish server?